# scanner validation for integer not functioning as supposed to

Tags: java

I'm having a bit of trouble with my code:

```
    int item = -1;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        while (!input.hasNextInt() || input.nextInt() > 5) {
            System.out.println("Enter a valid integer!");
            getMenu();
            input.next();
        }
        item = input.nextInt();
    } while (item <= 0);
    input.close();
```

If I enter anything below 5 it works. If I enter 6 it shows me that I have to enter a valid integer. When I try to enter 6 again nothing happens, but when I enter 6 AGAIN, then it will show me that message again. I think it has to do with the `input.next()` but not quite sure why.

Any ideas?

`getMenu()` just displays a bunch of strings btw.

So in other words. The user has to enter a valid integer between 1 and 5. If the user doesn't do that, he will loop through the block of code asking to enter a valid integer. The user will loop until he enters a valid integer.

Comment: What is `input.next();` supposed to do? You're not assigning it to anything.

Comment: I am unable to get what you want to achieve there, please share it , so that we can help you with a better code

Comment: Also, if `input.nextInt() > 5` ends up being false, you're not storing  that either, `item` ends up getting the *next* integer that is scanned.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel If I don't use `input.next()` I get stuck in a loop which keeps printing strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the **Scanner** inside the **do** block or **flush()** the value or use **nextLine()** to flush it

```
do {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (!input.hasNextInt() || input.nextInt() > 5) {
        System.out.println("Enter a valid integer!");
        //OR String a = input.nextLine():
        getMenu();
        input.next();
    }
```

Comment: This works. I used `nextLine()`

Answer (score 1):

You are reading 2 inputs in your `while` loop in case you enter `value > 5`. First value is read by `scan.nextInt()` itself. Then the `scan.next()` inside the loop also reads a token.

So, first time you pass `6`, the `while` loop condition will be satisified, and then `scan.next()` will wait for an input. And then, the second time you pass `6` is read by `scan.next()`.

Also, you can't remove the `scan.next()` from the loop, because in case `scan.hasNextInt()` condition becomes `false`, then the input won't be read by `scan.nextInt()`, and then your loop will go infinite, as `hasNextInt()` will keep on testing the same input.

To solve the issue, remove the 2nd condition from the `while` loop:

```
int item = -1;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

do {
    System.out.println("Enter integer value between [1,5]");

    while (!input.hasNextInt()) {  // iterate until invalid input is passed
        System.out.println("Enter a valid integer!");
        input.next();   // Read the invalid input to move the cursor ahead
    }
    item = input.nextInt();  // Valid input found, read it in `item`

} while (item <= 0 || item >= 6);

System.out.println(item);
input.close();
```